# How to iterate using partial text of href using selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvDisplayProducts','Page$2')" style="color:White;">2</a>
```

**Xpath:**

```
//*[@id="gvDisplayProducts"]/tbody/tr[28]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a
```

[These are page buttons that i need to click, above href and xpath is for one of the page button and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsUaL.png)

I am trying to loop through different pages of search result on a website. On XPATH the `td["value"]` goes from 1 to 10 for pages 1-10 and then for pages 11-20 the `td["value"]` becomes 1 to 10 again.

How can i iterate using the `'Page$i'` part of href. I cannot use the xpath because the xpath repeats again after reaching a certain page. Please let me know if i can iterate on just the `'Page$"i"'` part using selenium and python.

Comment: Please, paste part of the HTML, then we can help you better :)

Comment: Why can't you use xpath .?

Comment: You can use xpath to check for the href attribute value rm. What stopping you

Comment: Edited the question with html as well as xpath, please advise

Comment: It is a very small piece of code, could you provide a bit more and/or an url that would give us the big picture, please

Comment: @HedgeHog Cannot share images of website. Let me know what specifically are you looking for? The href or xpath are of a particular page..I want to iterate through the pages..Hope it is clear now.

Comment: @PratyushDash: Sorry, my mistake "Big Picture" do not mean image or screenshot :) provide just the url of the website. thx

Comment: The url doesn't change when i select different pages..it won't be of any use

Answer (score 0):

You can use python string format

```
elems = [driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//a[@href=\"javascript:__doPostBack('gvDisplayProducts','Page${i}')\"]") for i in range(10)]
```

This will give list of all elements as a list in the variable elems

if you change find elem to print the out is :

[image]

so see if the xpath you gave works , if that does this is the way to iterate over i in href in your xpath

**I added the element to a html file and tried to search using the xpath**

[image]

you can see its detected correctly

if in your case its not detected see if its inside iframe or you need webdriver waits

Comment: That is not a valid XPATH, so that won't work..Please refer to href and xpath above

Comment: //a[@href="javascript:__doPostBack('gvDisplayProducts','Page$2')"] are you able to find using this xpath ?  this the one you provided in the question

Comment: that is not the xpath..xpath is //*[@id="gvDisplayProducts"]/tbody/tr[28]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a